# How do I copy (Export & Import) a JetBrains PhpStorm project to another computer?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am switching computers, from one that I was developing on using PhpStorm to a new one), where one computer has version 2019.3 to version 2019.3.2. I've already exported the settings between the two computers, and now I want to copy the project settings too, not just the files.

How do I:

1. Export the Project from the 'old' computer?
2. Import the Project into the new computer?

When done, both computers should have the project on them.

Comment: Just copy whole project folder between computers, that's it. There is no "export" or "import" for project settings. Project-specific settings are stored inside `.idea` subfolder of your project root (although is latest version actual workspace (files opened, tool windows locations etc) is stored together with IDE settings...).

Comment: P.S. For IDE settings -- the same, just copy files between computers (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs). The only thing that may have some issues are logins & passwords -- depending on what storage was used, it may require different way of transferring them; in some cases you will need to re-enter that info again.

Comment: LazyOne, Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Project specific settings are stored in the .idea subdirectory of the project directory of your project.
So just copy your entire project folder over to your new computer.
After that you can simply re-open your project, either by using the 'open' button on the 'Welcome to PHPStorm' [image: 'open' button on the 'Welcome to PHPStorm'],

or if PHPStorm is already running by going to the 'File' menu and choosing 'Open'.
Potential project folders are already marked, like the workspaces dir in this picture:

[image: like the workspaces dir here]

Remember: It can happen that the .idea dir is not copied with the rest of the projectdir. Likely this is because it is a 'hidden' file (because it starts with a . ), be sure to double check this if you have trouble still.

Official docs here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html